# Routing checking user role Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I have two bundles and I want routes from one of the bundle only accessible if the user have a defined role.

The logic from the router matcher should be:

if the user have the role

```
| name             | path  | success |
|------------------|-------|---------|
| bundle_1_route_1 | /     | false   |
| bundle_1_route_2 | /test | true    |
```

If the user don't have the role

```
| name             | path  | success |
|------------------|-------|---------|
| bundle_1_route_1 | /     | false   |
| bundle_1_route_2 | /test | false   |
| bundle_2_route_1 | /aaa  | false   |
| bundle_2_route_2 | /test | true    |
```

The problem is I can't do that using the security because the path are the same

I tried with the `@security` annotation http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/security.html
But I have an access denied when on `bundle_1_route_2` with no role and the others urls are not checked.

I want to continue checking all the available url if the role is not matching

I found an other solution, but this is not very clean, and it will create error if the session does not exists

```
bundle_1:
    resource: "@Bundle1/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
    condition: "'ROLE_FILTER' in request.getSession().get('bundle1.user').getRoles()"
```

Is there a way to create completely custom conditions on routing ?